# Which n for base case if number defined on $\mathbb R$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have the following task

$S_n: (1 + x)^n \geq 1 + nx$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x > −1$

I am wondering which number to take for the base case in the inductive proof, because when I choose $0$, I will not have shown it for the real numbers in $(0,-1)$. When showing it for $-0.999999$, I will have decreased the interval for numbers that I have not proven to $(-0.999999,-1)$ which still contains numbers that I have not shown....What should I do?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, the interval $(0, - 1) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 < x < - 1\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: You *don't* choose $x$ for the base case. It's $n$ that you should deal with.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is by induction on $n$; you cannot do induction on $x$.

The proposition you want to prove by induction is

> for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, for every $x>-1$, $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$

Thus the family of propositions to prove true is

> $P(n)$: for every $x>-1$, $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$

The base case is $n=0$: $(1+x)^0=1$, $1+0x=1$. So $P(0)$ holds.

Induction step. Suppose $(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$. Then
$$
(1+x)^{n+1}=(1+x)(1+x)^n\ge(1+x)(1+nx)=1+(n+1)x+nx^2\ge1+(n+1)x
$$

You should *not* choose any $x$: the statements should hold *for every $x>-1$*.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show something stronger: show that it holds for all $x\geq -1$ instead.

Comment: Oh okay. Is that always the way to go?

Comment: @thebilly There is no "always the way to go". It's about having a bag of tricks and trying them all until one of them works.

Comment: I see. Is there a name for this bag of tricks, that I might be able to look up online? Or does that simply come by practice and experience?

Comment: @thebilly No. Everyone has their own, and like a real tool collection, it's something they build up as they encounter the tools, one by one.